# iPhone 3D Game Development using Maya?

Tags: 3d, ios, maya

I'm reading up on 3D game development for the iPhone. I'm looking into programs like Unity for 3D development. My question is are these the best ways to go for 3D development for the iPhone-Unity or say Shiva? Is it common to use other 3D programs like Maya? What would be the disadvantages of using Maya or 3DsMax-or is this not even a possibility for iPhone development?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe it's just a language barrier but there seems to be some misunderstanding here.

Maya and Max are 3D model authoring tools.  Either one of these are going to spit out models that pretty much whatever 3D engine you want can use.  It doesn't matter what platform it's going to be on.  How else would you author 3D models for your 3D engine?

As far as "which one", well, http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/

Comment: So I guess that's not what I'm understanding-do I not make the models in Unity itself? I actually have to use a 3D program to import my work into Unity?

Comment: That's right. You don't make models in unity.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be doing 3D Game Dev on the iPhone I would suggest:

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html 
He has code samples that imports models from blender.

Discussion of 3D Game Engines for iOS:
http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/05/3d-game-and-graphics-engines.html

Answer (score -3):

I'd say both are great packages.. Maya is a bit more geared towards Fikm as Max is to GAming.. but this line is pretty well blurred these days since Alias is now AutoDesk.  Just grab whichever package people around you are using.. this way you have someone to talk to locally and swap ideas etc... 
                              and keep it simple.

Comment: -1 Missing the point of the question (Tetrad nailed it)